# Sql query to filter out the overlapping dates

Tags: hql

| Version | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-11-23 | 2005-11-23 |
| 2 | 2005-11-23 | 2005-11-23 |
| 3 | 2005-11-23 | 2008-10-23 |
| 4 | 2008-10-23 | 2010-05-18 |
| 5 | 2011-05-13 | 2012-05-19 |

In the above table instead of keeping version 1,2,3,4 we can keep version 1 starting from '2005-11-23' to '2010-05-18' since all these verions are overlapping and keep version 5 as it is.

Ouput needed
..............

| Version | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-11-23 | 2010-05-18 |
| 5 | 2011-05-13 | 2012-05-19 |

How we can frame sql query for thi scenario?

Comment: True or false: In all cases, if you have two versions, numbered as `v1 < v2`, the `start_date` for `v1` will be less than or equal to the `start_date` for `v2`, and the `end_date` for `v1` will be less than or equal to the `end_date` for `v2`? Also, what is with the numerous incompatible database tags - are you looking for a single solution that will work in all those products? If not, please remove the irrelevant tags, so we will know what you are actually asking about.

Comment: To clarify: can you have, for example, version 8 from year 2023 to 2040, and version 9 brom 2025 to 2035? This would violate the condition I described above (later version, number 9, ends strictly before the end date of version 8). If such situations are possible, then the problem is significantly more difficult.

Comment: @RP89. . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to handle this -- assuming that you can create stable sort on the rows (which `version` provides) -- uses a cumulative maximum instead of `lag()`.

```
select min(version), min(start_date), min(end_date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_max_end_date >= start_date then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (order by start_date, version) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   max(end_date) over (order by start_date, version
                                       rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                                      ) as prev_max_end_date
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

This should work in any (reasonable) database.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=279409c443d5df03f7d0fd0b074db7d7) is a db<>fiddle that happens to use Postgres.

The issue with `lag()`/`lead()` approaches is that the overlap with earlier rows may not be on the "previous" row.  For instance, consider this diagram (where lower case means start and upper case means end):

```
---a----b--B----c--C----d--D--e---A--E--
```

`E` overlaps with `A`.  However, by any reasonable definition of "previous", `A` is not the previous row for `E`.

Comment: unbounded preceding and 1 preceding this function available in hive?

Comment: @RP89 . . . (1) If you are using Hive, that should be the tag you use.  (2) Yes (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-PARTITIONBYwithpartitioning,ORDERBY,andwindowspecification).

Comment: ....Thank You..this works as expected and amazing solution

Answer (score 2):

***Hive or Postgresql***

```
CREATE TABLE my_dates (
  "Version" INTEGER,
  start_date date,
  end_date date
);

INSERT INTO my_dates
  ("Version",start_date, end_date)
VALUES
  ('1', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('2', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('3', '2005-11-23', '2008-10-23'),
  ('4', '2008-10-23', '2010-05-18'),
  ('5', '2011-05-13', '2012-05-19');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with my_overlaps AS (
select 
   *,
   LAG(end_date) OVER (ORDER BY "Version") >= start_date as  overlap
from my_dates
),
selected AS (
SELECT 
    "Version",
    start_date, 
    end_date ,
    LEAD("Version") OVER (ORDER BY "Version") AS next_version 
FROM 
    my_overlaps 
where overlap=false or 
      overlap is null 
)
select 
   s."Version",
   s.start_date, 
   CASE
       WHEN md.end_date IS NULL THEN s.end_date
       ELSE md.end_date
   END as end_date
FROM
   selected s
LEFT JOIN
   my_dates md on s.next_version -1 = md."Version";
```

| Version | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-11-23T00:00:00.000Z | 2010-05-18T00:00:00.000Z |
| 5 | 2011-05-13T00:00:00.000Z | 2012-05-19T00:00:00.000Z |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wDrP291tf3RAgwnSvbiozQ/4)

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_dates (
  "Version" INTEGER,
  start_date date,
  end_date date
);

INSERT INTO my_dates
  ("Version",start_date, end_date)
VALUES
  ('1', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('2', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('3', '2005-11-23', '2008-10-23'),
  ('4', '2008-10-23', '2010-05-18'),
  ('5', '2011-05-13', '2012-05-19');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with my_overlaps AS (
select 
   *,
   LAG(end_date) OVER (ORDER BY "Version") >= start_date as  overlap
from my_dates
),
selected AS (
SELECT 
    "Version",
    start_date, 
    end_date ,
    LEAD("Version") OVER (ORDER BY "Version") AS next_version 
FROM 
    my_overlaps 
where overlap=false or 
      overlap is null 
)
select 
   s."Version",
   s.start_date::text, 
   CASE
       WHEN md.end_date IS NULL THEN s.end_date::text
       ELSE md.end_date::text
   END as end_date
FROM
   selected s
LEFT JOIN
   my_dates md on s.next_version -1 = md."Version";
```

| Version | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-11-23 | 2010-05-18 |
| 5 | 2011-05-13 | 2012-05-19 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wDrP291tf3RAgwnSvbiozQ/5)

### Update 1

`Lag/Lead` functions now assigned default values

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_dates (
  "Version" INTEGER,
  start_date date,
  end_date date
);

INSERT INTO my_dates
  ("Version",start_date, end_date)
VALUES
  ('1', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('2', '2005-11-23', '2012-05-19');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with my_overlaps AS (
select 
   *,
   LAG(end_date,1,null) OVER (ORDER BY "Version") >= start_date as  overlap
from my_dates
),
selected AS (
SELECT 
    "Version",
    start_date, 
    end_date ,
    LEAD("Version",1,3) OVER (ORDER BY "Version") AS next_version 
FROM 
    my_overlaps 
where overlap=false or 
      overlap is null 
)
select 
   s."Version",
   s.start_date::text, 
   CASE
       WHEN md.end_date IS NULL THEN s.end_date::text
       ELSE md.end_date::text
   END as end_date
FROM
   selected s
LEFT JOIN
   my_dates md on s.next_version -1 = md."Version";
ORDER BY
   s."Version";
```

| Version | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-11-23 | 2012-05-19 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wDrP291tf3RAgwnSvbiozQ/6)

***With original dataset***
**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_dates (
  "Version" INTEGER,
  start_date date,
  end_date date
);

INSERT INTO my_dates
  ("Version",start_date, end_date)
VALUES
  ('1', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('2', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('3', '2005-11-23', '2008-10-23'),
  ('4', '2008-10-23', '2010-05-18'),
  ('5', '2011-05-13', '2012-05-19');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with my_overlaps AS (
select 
   *,
   LAG(end_date,1,null) OVER (ORDER BY "Version") >= start_date as  overlap
from my_dates
),
selected AS (
SELECT 
    "Version",
    start_date, 
    end_date ,
    LEAD("Version",1,3) OVER (ORDER BY "Version") AS next_version 
FROM 
    my_overlaps 
where overlap=false or 
      overlap is null 
)
select 
   s."Version",
   s.start_date::text, 
   CASE
       WHEN md.end_date IS NULL THEN s.end_date::text
       ELSE md.end_date::text
   END as end_date
FROM
   selected s
LEFT JOIN
   my_dates md on s.next_version -1 = md."Version"
ORDER BY
   s."Version";
```

| Version | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2005-11-23 | 2010-05-18 |
| 5 | 2011-05-13 | 2005-11-23 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wDrP291tf3RAgwnSvbiozQ/7)

Comment: Here I need version 1 end_date as '2010-05-18'

Comment: Super...This resolves my issue..Thanks a lot

Comment: I see one issue..when  table has records like this ('1', '2005-11-23', '2005-11-23'),
  ('2', '2005-11-23', '2012-05-19'), I need result as  ('1', '2005-11-23','2012-05-19')

Comment: @RP89 I've included an update by specifying default values for the lag function. It would be interesting to determine which approach is more efficient using the `EXPLAIN`

Comment: Thank You ggordon, i will check and update